# What's the best way to write Resque-related specs in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, redis, resque

What's the best way to write Resque-related specs in RSpec [without stubbing the former](http://github.com/leshill/resque_spec)?

We currently use the following helper:

```
@dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

def start_redis
  `redis-server #{@dir}/redis-test.conf`
  Resque.redis = "localhost:9736"
end

def stop_redis
  `rm -f #{@dir}/dump.rdb`
  pid = `ps -A -o pid,command | grep [r]edis-test`.split(" ")[0]
  Process.kill("KILL", pid.to_i)
end

Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    start_redis
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    stop_redis
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    Resque.redis.flushall
  end
end
```

Heavily borrowing from Resque's own test helper, this works fine but spews out an annoying `zsh: killed rake` when the entire spec suite is run through rake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's resque's recommendation for how best to run Redis processes in your specs:

https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/RSpec-and-Resque

Answer (score 6):

You can use the resque_spec gem http://github.com/leshill/resque_spec . A bunch of matcher to test resque.

Comment: That stubs Resque, which is fine for unit testing I suppose, but I prefer to run an actual instance of Resque to write more complex integration tests.

Seems we'll have to do with the above for now.

Comment: @HakanEnsari, did you ever end up doing anything different for your spec? I'm in the process of writing a test which requires integration of resque (using resque_mailer) and I'm stumped.